# Mouse, drawing and slider images

Tags: c#, image, xna, mouse, draw

I am trying to make a slider for the music, sound effects and resolution, 2 of them work but one is being bad:

[image]

I have 4 classes that interact with the images. the first is the `Images.cs` class, it calls all the images and puts them in the `Content` method. My main class holds the `Content` method and then updates the images that are size by the `Resize.cs` class and placed in there correct spots by the `Options.cs` class.

`Images` and `Resize` should not be the problem because they do not interact with the drawing of the images. The way the images are drawn matters (if you draw the background last it will cover every other image, so you need to draw it first).

Here is the code (Some code as been taken out because of limitations):

Game1.cs:

```
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        #region Define
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        public static SpriteFont font1;
        private static StartUp.Resize resize;
        private StartUp.TitleScreen titlescreen;
        private StartUp.Options options;
        private StartUp.Credits credits;

        Rectangle background = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);

        enum GameStates { StartUp, TitleScreen, Options, Credits, Paused, Playing, Death, Continue }
        GameStates gameState = GameStates.TitleScreen;

        #region Mouse
        float mouseDelay = 0.01f;
        float mouseTime = 0.0f;
        public static bool mouseActive = true;
        public static bool mouseUsed = false;
        public static string mouseOn = "None";
        public static Vector2 mouseLocation;
        #endregion

        #region Slider
        public static int sliderMax;
        public static int sliderMin;
        #endregion
        #endregion

        #region Initialize
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            this.IsMouseVisible = true;
            resize = new StartUp.Resize();
            options = new StartUp.Options();
            titlescreen = new StartUp.TitleScreen();
            StartUp.Options.Initialize();
            base.Initialize();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Update
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            // Allows the game to exit
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                this.Exit();

            #region SetUp
            sliderMin = (resize.size * 69) + ((resize.size * 1));
            sliderMax = (resize.size * 69) + ((resize.size * 32));
            #endregion

            if (this.IsMouseVisible == true)
            {
                #region Mouse
                mouseTime += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

                MouseState mouse = Mouse.GetState();

                mouseLocation = new Vector2(mouse.X, mouse.Y);

                #region GameState Switch
                switch (gameState)
                {
                    case GameStates.TitleScreen:
                        StartUp.TitleScreen.Update(gameTime);
                        break;
                    case GameStates.Options:
                        StartUp.Options.Update(gameTime);
                        break;
                    case GameStates.Credits:
                        break;
                }
                #endregion

                if (mouseOn != "None")
                {
                    mouseUsed = true;

                    #region GameState Switch
                    switch (gameState)
                    {
                        case GameStates.TitleScreen:
                            if (mouseOn == "Continue")
                                gameState = GameStates.Continue;
                            else if (mouseOn == "Credits")
                                gameState = GameStates.Credits;
                            else if (mouseOn == "Exit")
                                this.Exit();
                            else if (mouseOn == "Logo")
                                gameState = GameStates.TitleScreen;
                            else if (mouseOn == "Options")
                                gameState = GameStates.Options;
                            else if (mouseOn == "Play")
                                gameState = GameStates.Playing;
                            else if (mouseOn == "Version")
                                gameState = GameStates.TitleScreen;
                            else
                                mouseOn = "None";
                            break;
                        case GameStates.Options:
                            if (mouseOn == "Main Menu")
                                gameState = GameStates.TitleScreen;
                            if (mouseOn == "Ok")
                            {
                            }
                            else if (mouseOn == "Off")
                            {
                                graphics.IsFullScreen = false;
                                graphics.ApplyChanges();
                            }
                            else if (mouseOn == "On")
                            {
                                graphics.IsFullScreen = true;
                                graphics.ApplyChanges();
                            }
                            break;
                        case GameStates.Credits:
                            break;
                    }
                    #endregion

                    mouseOn = "None";
                }

                if (mouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
                {
                    mouseTime = 0.0f;
                    mouseActive = false;
                }

                if (mouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released && mouseTime > mouseDelay)
                {
                    mouseActive = true;
                    mouseUsed = false;
                }
                #endregion
            }

            #region GameState Switch
            switch (gameState)
            {
                case GameStates.StartUp:
                    break;
                case GameStates.TitleScreen:
                    StartUp.TitleScreen.Update(gameTime);
                    break;
                case GameStates.Options:
                    StartUp.Options.Update(gameTime);
                    break;
                case GameStates.Credits:
                    break;
            }
            #endregion

            #region Image Resize
            if ((gameState == GameStates.TitleScreen ||
                gameState == GameStates.Credits ||
                gameState == GameStates.Options ||
                gameState == GameStates.Continue) &&
                (resize.change == true))
            {
                resize.change = false;
                resize.backgroundHeight = resize.size * StartUp.Images.Background.Height;
                resize.backgroundWidth = resize.size * StartUp.Images.Background.Width;
                resize.backgroundX = 0;
                resize.backgroundY = 0;
                graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = resize.backgroundHeight;
                graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = resize.backgroundWidth;
                graphics.ApplyChanges();

                background = new Rectangle(resize.backgroundX, resize.backgroundY, resize.backgroundWidth, resize.backgroundHeight);
                //Background's rectangle is located in the draw method.

                resize.sliderHeight = resize.size * StartUp.Images.Slider.Height;
                resize.sliderWidth = resize.size * StartUp.Images.Slider.Width;
                options.sliderX = resize.size * 70;
                options.sliderY = resize.size * 38;
                StartUp.Options.slide = new Rectangle(options.sliderX, options.sliderY, resize.sliderWidth, resize.sliderHeight);

                resize.sliderHeight = resize.size * StartUp.Images.Slider.Height;
                resize.sliderWidth = resize.size * StartUp.Images.Slider.Width;
                options.slider2X = resize.size * 70;
                options.slider2Y = resize.size * 52;
                StartUp.Options.slide2 = new Rectangle(options.slider2X, options.slider2Y, resize.sliderWidth, resize.sliderHeight);

                resize.sliderHeight = resize.size * StartUp.Images.Slider.Height;
                resize.sliderWidth = resize.size * StartUp.Images.Slider.Width;
                options.slider3X = resize.size * 70;
                options.slider3Y = resize.size * 63;
                StartUp.Options.slide3 = new Rectangle(options.slider3X, options.slider3Y, resize.sliderWidth, resize.sliderHeight);

                resize.sliderbackgroundHeight = resize.size * StartUp.Images.SliderBackground.Height;
                resize.sliderbackgroundWidth = resize.size * StartUp.Images.SliderBackground.Width;
                options.sliderbackgroundX = resize.size * 69;
                options.sliderbackgroundY = resize.size * 36;
                StartUp.Options.slideback = new Rectangle(options.sliderbackgroundX, options.sliderbackgroundY, resize.sliderbackgroundWidth, resize.sliderbackgroundHeight);

                resize.sliderbackgroundHeight = resize.size * StartUp.Images.SliderBackground.Height;
                resize.sliderbackgroundWidth = resize.size * StartUp.Images.SliderBackground.Width;
                options.sliderbackground2X = resize.size * 69;
                options.sliderbackground2Y = resize.size * 50;
                StartUp.Options.slideback2 = new Rectangle(options.sliderbackground2X, options.sliderbackground2Y, resize.sliderbackgroundWidth, resize.sliderbackgroundHeight);

                resize.sliderbackgroundHeight = resize.size * StartUp.Images.SliderBackground.Height;
                resize.sliderbackgroundWidth = resize.size * StartUp.Images.SliderBackground.Width;
                options.sliderbackground3X = resize.size * 69;
                options.sliderbackground3Y = resize.size * 64;
                StartUp.Options.slideback3 = new Rectangle(options.sliderbackground3X, options.sliderbackground3Y, resize.sliderbackgroundWidth, resize.sliderbackgroundHeight);
            }
            #endregion

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Draw
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            if (gameState == GameStates.TitleScreen ||
                gameState == GameStates.Options ||
                gameState == GameStates.Credits)
            {
                spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.FrontToBack, BlendState.AlphaBlend, SamplerState.PointClamp, DepthStencilState.Default, RasterizerState.CullCounterClockwise);
                spriteBatch.Draw(StartUp.Images.Background, background, Color.White);
                spriteBatch.End();
            }

            if (gameState == GameStates.TitleScreen)
            {
                StartUp.TitleScreen.Draw(spriteBatch);
            }

            if (gameState == GameStates.Options)
            {
                StartUp.Options.Draw(spriteBatch);

                spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.FrontToBack, BlendState.AlphaBlend, SamplerState.PointClamp, DepthStencilState.Default, RasterizerState.CullCounterClockwise);
                if (graphics.IsFullScreen == true)
                {
                    spriteBatch.Draw(StartUp.Images.OffNotSelected, StartUp.Options.offnot, Color.White);
                    spriteBatch.Draw(StartUp.Images.OnSelected, StartUp.Options.onsel, Color.White);
                }
                else
                {
                    spriteBatch.Draw(StartUp.Images.OffSelected, StartUp.Options.offsel, Color.White);
                    spriteBatch.Draw(StartUp.Images.OnNotSelected, StartUp.Options.onnot, Color.White);
                }
                spriteBatch.End();
            }

            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
            {
                spriteBatch.Begin();
                spriteBatch.Draw(StartUp.Images.Transparent, new Rectangle(0, 0, 800, 300), Color.White);
                //debug 1
                spriteBatch.DrawString(font1, "Resize", new Vector2(0, 0), Color.White);
                spriteBatch.DrawString(font1, StartUp.Options.res.ToString(), new Vector2(0, 20), Color.White);
                spriteBatch.DrawString(font1, options.resX.ToString(), new Vector2(0, 40), Color.White);
                spriteBatch.DrawString(font1, options.resY.ToString(), new Vector2(0, 60), Color.White);
                spriteBatch.DrawString(font1, resize.resHeight.ToString(), new Vector2(0, 80), Color.White);
                spriteBatch.DrawString(font1, resize.resWidth.ToString(), new Vector2(0, 100), Color.White);

                //debug2
                spriteBatch.DrawString(font1, "Slider", new Vector2(380, 0), Color.White);
                spriteBatch.DrawString(font1, "sliderMin: " + sliderMin.ToString(), new Vector2(380, 20), Color.White);
                spriteBatch.DrawString(font1, "sliderMax: " + sliderMax.ToString(), new Vector2(380, 40), Color.White);
                spriteBatch.DrawString(font1, StartUp.Options.thing.ToString(), new Vector2(380, 60), Color.White);

                //debug3
                spriteBatch.DrawString(font1, "Background", new Vector2(0, 120), Color.White);
                spriteBatch.DrawString(font1, background.ToString(), new Vector2(0, 140), Color.White);
                spriteBatch.DrawString(font1, resize.backgroundHeight.ToString(), new Vector2(0, 160), Color.White);
                spriteBatch.DrawString(font1, resize.backgroundWidth.ToString(), new Vector2(0, 180), Color.White);
                spriteBatch.DrawString(font1, resize.backgroundX.ToString(), new Vector2(0, 200), Color.White);
                spriteBatch.DrawString(font1, resize.backgroundY.ToString(), new Vector2(0, 220), Color.White);
                //debug4
                spriteBatch.DrawString(font1, "Mouse", new Vector2(380, 120), Color.White);
                spriteBatch.DrawString(font1, "mouseDelay: " + mouseDelay.ToString(), new Vector2(380, 140), Color.White);
                spriteBatch.DrawString(font1, "mouseTime: " + mouseTime.ToString(), new Vector2(380, 160), Color.White);
                spriteBatch.DrawString(font1, "mouseActive: " + mouseActive.ToString(), new Vector2(380, 180), Color.White);
                spriteBatch.DrawString(font1, "mouseUsed: " + mouseUsed.ToString(), new Vector2(380, 200), Color.White);
                spriteBatch.DrawString(font1, "mouseOn: " + mouseOn.ToString(), new Vector2(380, 220), Color.White);
                spriteBatch.DrawString(font1, "mouseLocation: " + mouseLocation.ToString(), new Vector2(380, 240), Color.White);
                spriteBatch.End();
            }
            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Options.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace **.StartUp
{
    class Options
    {
        #region Define
        private static Resize resize;

        public static bool thing;

        public int resX;
        public int resY;

        public int optionslogoX;
        public int optionslogoY;

        public int offnotselectedX;
        public int offnotselectedY;

        public int offselectedX;
        public int offselectedY;

        public int okX;
        public int okY;

        public int onnotselectedX;
        public int onnotselectedY;

        public int onselectedX;
        public int onselectedY;

        public int fullscreenX;
        public int fullscreenY;

        public int menuX;
        public int menuY;

        public int musicX;
        public int musicY;

        public int resolutionX;
        public int resolutionY;

        public int sliderbackgroundX;
        public int sliderbackgroundY;

        public int sliderbackground2X;
        public int sliderbackground2Y;

        public int sliderbackground3X;
        public int sliderbackground3Y;

        public int sliderX;
        public int sliderY;

        public int slider2X;
        public int slider2Y;

        public int slider3X;
        public int slider3Y;

        public int soundfxX;
        public int soundfxY;

        public static Rectangle full;
        public static Rectangle menu;
        public static Rectangle music;
        public static Rectangle slideback;
        public static Rectangle slideback2;
        public static Rectangle slideback3;
        public static Rectangle ok;
        public static Rectangle slide;
        public static Rectangle slide2;
        public static Rectangle slide3;
        public static Rectangle sound;
        public static Rectangle optionslogo;
        public static Rectangle offnot;
        public static Rectangle offsel;
        public static Rectangle onnot;
        public static Rectangle onsel;
        public static Rectangle resolution;
        public static Rectangle res;
        #endregion

        #region Update and Draw
        public static void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            #region Mouse
            MouseState mouse = Mouse.GetState();

            if (mouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && Game1.mouseUsed == false && Game1.mouseActive == true)
            {
                if (menu.Contains(mouse.X, mouse.Y))
                {
                    Game1.mouseOn = "Main Menu";
                    Game1.mouseUsed = true;
                }
                else if (ok.Contains(mouse.X, mouse.Y))
                {
                    Game1.mouseOn = "Ok";
                    Game1.mouseUsed = true;
                }
                else if (offnot.Contains(mouse.X, mouse.Y))
                {
                    Game1.mouseOn = "Off";
                    Game1.mouseUsed = true;
                }
                else if (onnot.Contains(mouse.X, mouse.Y))
                {
                    Game1.mouseOn = "On";
                    Game1.mouseUsed = true;
                }
                else if (slide.Contains(mouse.X, mouse.Y))
                {
                    Game1.mouseOn = "Slide";
                    Game1.mouseUsed = true;
                }
                else if (slide2.Contains(mouse.X, mouse.Y))
                {
                    Game1.mouseOn = "Slide2";
                    Game1.mouseUsed = true;
                }
                else if (slide3.Contains(mouse.X, mouse.Y))
                {
                    Game1.mouseOn = "Slide3";
                    Game1.mouseUsed = true;
                }
            }
            #endregion

            #region Slider
            if (mouse.X >= Game1.sliderMin && mouse.X <= Game1.sliderMax)
                thing = true;
            else
                thing = false;

            if (mouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && slideback.Contains(mouse.X, mouse.Y) && (mouse.X >= (Game1.sliderMin + (1 * resize.size))) && (mouse.X <= Game1.sliderMax))
            {
                slide.X = mouse.X - 1 * resize.size;
            }
            if (mouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && slideback2.Contains(mouse.X, mouse.Y) && (mouse.X >= (Game1.sliderMin + (1 * resize.size))) && (mouse.X <= Game1.sliderMax))
            {
                slide2.X = mouse.X - 1 * resize.size;
            }
            if (mouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && slideback3.Contains(mouse.X, mouse.Y) && (mouse.X >= (Game1.sliderMin + (1 * resize.size))) && (mouse.X <= Game1.sliderMax))
            {
                slide3.X = mouse.X - 1 * resize.size;
            }
            #endregion
        }

        public static void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.FrontToBack, BlendState.AlphaBlend, SamplerState.PointClamp, DepthStencilState.Default, RasterizerState.CullCounterClockwise);
            spriteBatch.Draw(Images.Res1, res, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.Draw(Images.Res2, res, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.Draw(Images.Res3, res, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.Draw(Images.Res4, res, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.Draw(Images.Res5, res, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.Draw(Images.Res6, res, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.Draw(Images.Res7, res, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.Draw(Images.Res8, res, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.Draw(Images.Ok, ok, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.Draw(Images.OptionsLogo, optionslogo, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.Draw(Images.FullScreen, full, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.Draw(Images.Menu, menu, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.Draw(Images.Music, music, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.Draw(Images.Resolution, resolution, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.Draw(Images.SliderBackground, slideback, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.Draw(Images.SliderBackground, slideback2, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.Draw(Images.SliderBackground, slideback3, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.Draw(Images.Slider, slide, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.Draw(Images.Slider, slide2, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.Draw(Images.Slider, slide3, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.Draw(Images.SoundFX, sound, Color.White);
            spriteBatch.End();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Method
        #endregion

        #region In
        public static void Initialize()
        {
            resize = new Resize();
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, please, try to avoid posting all of your code in a question, it's frustrating to read. You should post only the relevant code, in this way it's easier to understand.

Comment: And just a suggestion, you can declare multiple variables using a `,` between them. I mean `int var1, var2, var3... ;` That thing is really awful.

Comment: @pinckerman Thank you for the incite, I will keep that in mind when posting in the future. I only put down the code fully is because I did not know if it was in an int or some other part of the code in `Game1.cs`. Thank you for the help and will try the out the code that you posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.FrontToBack, ...);
```

but you are not setting `layerDepth` parameter of `SpriteBatch.Draw` method.

If you want every sprite to be drawn in the order you call the Draw, you should use `SpriteSortMode.Deferred`.

Otherwise, if you want to use `FrontToBack` you need to use a different overload for `SpriteBatch.Draw`, for example:

```
public void Draw (
     Texture2D texture,
     Vector2 position,
     Nullable<Rectangle> sourceRectangle,
     Color color,
     float rotation,
     Vector2 origin,
     float scale,
     SpriteEffects effects,
     float layerDepth
)
```

in this way you can set `layerDepth` parameter to specify the depth of each sprite.
Ad MSDN says:

> The depth of a layer. By default, 0 represents the front layer and 1
>   represents a back layer. Use SpriteSortMode if you want sprites to be
>   sorted during drawing.

Reference: [Draw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433988.aspx) method and [SpriteSortMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritesortmode.aspx) enumeration.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I am sorry that the code was messy and hard to read, I am trying my best as a first year of coding to sort and keep the code in a neat and orderly fashion.